# HTML Stretch image height to parent div that resizes to content?

Tags: html, css, styling

So I'm creating a recent blog posts page similar to that of BuzzFeed's homepage feed. The problem I am having is with the thumbnail image. I want it to look like this where the image stretches to the parent div but when I set height to 100% it just fit's the screen.

[image: via Buzzfeed]

Parent Div

```
  .post {
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px #E8E8E8 solid;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Child Div

```
.post img {
    width: 33.33333%!important;
    float: left;
}
```

I have removed any height for the sake of showing the bare bones of the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: look into `object-fit:cover`

Comment: @MarineLeBorgne doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Genthorn: Did you try: `height: auto !important;` Give a try... it should work. e.g. `.post img {width: 33.33333% !important; height: auto !important; float: left;}`